# How to get scroll to a list item in a page that has multiple lists

Tags: sapui5

I have three lists in a page where when one item is selected the other item cannot be selected in other lists. I have written code that focuses on the selected list item when I navigate to that page. Now, the issue is that it's not focusing and `addEventDelegate` isn't working for the lists. The focus code is getting executed and again the scroll bar is moving to the top.

Initially I tried like this:

```
tList.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function() {
        debugger;
        var a = sap.ui.getCore().byId("typesList").getSelectedItems()[0];
        if(a != undefined) { 
            $("#"+a.sId)[0].focus();
        }
    }
}, this)
cList.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function() {
        debugger;
        var a = sap.ui.getCore().byId("catList").getSelectedItems()[0];
        if(a != undefined) { 
            $("#"+a.sId)[0].focus();
        }
    }
}, cList)
sList.addEventDelegate({
    onAfterRendering: function() {
        debugger;
        var a = sap.ui.getCore().byId("statList").getSelectedItems()[0];
        if(a != undefined) { 
            $("#"+a.sId)[0].focus();
        }
    }
}, sList)
```

It didn't work. `onAfterRendering` is never getting fired. I tried this:

```
onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    debugger;
    var tList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("typesList");
    var cList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("catList");
    var sList = sap.ui.getCore().byId("statList");
    var typesItem = sap.ui.getCore().byId("typesList").getSelectedItems()[0];
    if(typesItem != undefined) { 
        $("#"+typesItem.sId)[0].focus();
    }
    var catItem = sap.ui.getCore().byId("catList").getSelectedItems()[0];
    if(catItem != undefined) { 
        var i = cList.indexOfItem(catItem);
        //$("#"+catItem.sId)[0].focus();
        cList.getItems()[i].focus(); 
    }
    var statItem = sap.ui.getCore().byId("statList").getSelectedItems()[0];
    if(statItem != undefined) { 
        $("#"+statItem.sId)[0].focus();
    }
}
```

It's working well but I don't know why the scroll bar is moving to the top of the view after executing this code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Discussed on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322657/601179)

Comment: I guess you are using `sap.m.List`. You shouldn't ever need to change the DOM (using jQuery) directly. ListBase got a [setSelectedItems](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#setSelectedItem) for this case. Also the ListItem should have [`type=Active`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListItemBase.html#getType) because, as far as I know, `Inactive` items can't be `Selected`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.My item is getting selected.The problem is with scroll bar.I want to focus the item that is selected in one of the three lists.The scrollbar is moving to the selected list item and again moving upwards

Answer (score 1):

Use `.getDomRef().focus()`

You have to be careful trying to scroll to a list item. If your view, list or
items haven't been rendered in the DOM, this will error out. So write some code to protect against that.

In the example below, I check to see if the DOM reference for the selected list item exists. If it does, call `.focus()` to scroll to it. If the DOM reference doesn't exist, I add an event delegate to the list to be called after the list has been rendered, which then scrolls to the selected item.

```
_scrollToListItem: function() {
    var oItemDomRef = this.getView().byId("list").getSelectedItem().getDomRef();
    if (!oItemDomRef) {
        this.getView().byId("list").addEventDelegate({
            onAfterRendering: function() {
                this._scrollToListItem();
            }.bind(this)
        });
    } else {
        oItemDomRef.focus();
    }
}
```